Relation between symplectic volume form and volume induced by Sasaki metric
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Then the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ has a natural symplectic structure $\omega$ and carries an associated volume form $\Omega = \frac{1}{d!}\omega^d$.
The tangent bundle $TM$ can be considered as a Riemannian manifold in its own right by considering $TTM = TM\oplus TM$ using the horizontal and vertical lift. This leads to the Sasaki metric and an associated Riemannian volume form on $TM$, which I think of as a kind of product measure of the Riemannian volume form on $M$.
Now there is the natural isomorphism $\phi\colon TM\to T^*M$ given by $\phi(v) = (w\mapsto g(v,w))$ between the tangent and cotangent bundles. My question is: How are the two volume forms related?
In particular, any Hamiltonian flow on $T^*M$ preservers the symplectic volume form. Considering the flow on $TM$ of an associated (regular) Lagrangian vector field, what is the corresponding preserved volume? Does it coincide with the volume induced by the Sasaki metric?

If you'll excuse a lazy comment: Have you worked out what happens for the Euclidean metric, or for an orthogonal metric $E, du^2 + G, dv^2$ in the plane?
